# Sharing UIImageView between View Controllers in TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` based app. I've made a `masterVC` Class, all ViewControllers that make up the `tabBarController` are subclasses of the `masterVC`. I want to set an UIImageView (which is a property of `masterVC`) that once set shows that image on each view within the `tabBarController`.

If I was instantiating each VC I could pass the image as a property (this would be simple). However, there's no method to do this between tabBarController ViewControllers.

The easiest conceptual example of what I'm trying to do is by this example in each view Controller within the tabBarController. There has to be a better way:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:kMainImageData];
    if (data) {
        self.mainImageView.image = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.mainImageView.image];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:kMainImageData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is, create a proper data source, where each `UIViewController` can request data. There are some ways:

- Save the image to disk, use a helper class to retrieve it.
- Save the image as property of a Singleton and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the method

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
```

With something like this:

```
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if ( self )
{
    static UIImage *reuseImage = nil;

    if ( reuseImage == nil )
    {
        //Init reuseImage with your image
    }

    myImageViewProperty.image = reuseImage;
...
return self;
```

Comment: Dan, I'm not familiar with initWithCoder methods. Would this part: '//Init reuseImage with your image' be where I initially set the image?

Comment: @Eric Yes, it would be, however you initialize it, if you're loading it from a resource, or from some downloaded data, or whatnot.  The `initWithCoder` method is an init method that is called on view controlelrs that are instantiated through XIB or storyboards

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you can do this all in your superclass with key-value observing.

In your `masterVC` header, declare:

```
@property (strong) UIImage *sharedImage;
```

And in the implementation:

```
@synthesize sharedImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sharedImage" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"sharedImage"]) {
        self.mainImageView.image = self.sharedImage;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sharedImage"];
}
```

Then, whenever the `sharedImage` property is set on any of the subclasses, your image view will update its contents accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing would be to move the `viewDidAppear` method you posted into your `masterVC` class. Then in your ViewControllers that subclass `masterVC` you can:

Remove the `viewDidAppear` method if you have no other setup to do, it will then call the `viewDidAppear` that is in your `masterVC`.

OR

Change `viewDidAppear` to the following so that it will call `viewDidAppear` in `masterVC` then do all your other setup.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // your other code...
}
```